# Dockerfile - How to append PATH using ENV instruction?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The `ENV` instruction sets the environment variable  to the value . This value will be in the environment for all subsequent instructions in the build stage

---

Below instruction:

```
   ENV PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
```

does not append `PATH` variable

`$HOME/go/bin` is `/root/go/bin`

How to append `$HOME/go/bin` to `$PATH`? in below docker file

```
FROM golang:1.14.10
MAINTAINER xyz

ENV GOPATH=

ENV PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin

RUN echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Docker doesn't let you use environment variables defined outside of your `Dockerfile` within an `ENV` or `ARG` declaration.

As a workaround, you can pass the names/directories to your `Dockerfile` explicitly using **[`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)**:

```
FROM golang:1.14.10
    
# set default to `root`
ARG USERNAME=root

ENV PATH=$PATH:/$USERNAME/go/bin

RUN echo $PATH
```

You can then pass the `USERNAME` via `docker build --build-arg USERNAME=myuser`

Depending on your usecase you can also do this using a **`RUN`** or **`ENTRYPOINT`**.

Comment: **1)** I didn't get this.. "The problem is that `$HOME` isn't defined yet". `$HOME` is suppose to be defined in Dockerfile? this line(`ENV PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`) runs in container right? `$HOME` is defined there.. **2)** Are you saying `ENV PATH=$PATH:${USERNAME}/go/bin` in the next part of the answer?

Comment: @overexchange sorry about that, I was tired when I wrote this.   Both your points are correct.  **1)** `$HOME` is defined, and I was being too presumptuous about the cause of the issue.  **2)** I made a typo and forgot to include `$USERNAME` in the declaration

Comment: If `$PATH` & `$HOME` is defined in docker container, then am trying to understand, what is the implication of writing `ENV PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin` in `Dockerfile` and run `docker build`? Does it work?

Comment: @overexchange no it doesn't, and I'm not sure why.  For some reason, it only works when you have *explicitly defined variables* like in my example.

Comment: same issue! not able to use $HOME with ENV command. But i'm able to echo $HOME. Weird

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion is this: when you say $HOME in ENV, home isn't defined yet. But when you say RUN echo $HOME, home is defined by the shell in the base image.

PATH is working and causing confusion, because it's defined by the base image you're using with FROM.

ENV is used to define default variables for the image that will be built, and that will be accessible in RUN statements. Think of it this way: the Dockerfile can provide variables to the container, but the container cannot provide variables to the Dockerfile.

Really, I would just hardcode in /root if root is the user you want to run from. The variables provided by the build are meant to be *defaults* if you want to do something fancy and dynamic, you probably are better off injecting a script into your image, and running that.

Answer (score 0):

As per mentioned here in [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)

I tried using this format and it worked with me:

```
ENV gradle=/opt/gradle/gradle-6.6.1/bin
ENV PATH=${gradle}:${PATH}
```